# Event handling between 2 projects

Tags: c#, events, delegates

I have 2 projects in a single solution. I have a button in 1st project and i have to write event for that in 2nd project. There is no reference b/w  1st and 2nd but the 2nd project having reference with project 1. Can we able to do that using Delegates and events?

Answer (score 1):

In the project which has the button, make the button and the form `public`, then in the other project, add a reference to that project and you can use

```
whateverProject.whateverForm.whateverButton.Click += MyEventHandler;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. you must follow these steps :
right-click Project2 and select Add Reference then under Projects select Project1.

you must use this code at the top of the Project2 source file :

```
using Project1;  // for replacing Project1 with the namespace of your Project1
```

now you must get and set. for example you have lable and textbox so you must you these codes :

```
public string TextBox1_text    
        {           
            get { return TextBox1.Text; }           
            set { TextBox1.Text = value; }          
        }  

    public string lable1_text       
    {           
        get { return label1.Text; }           
        set { label1.Text = value; }          
    }
```